# Haskell Weird Kinds: Kind of (->) is ?? -> ? -> *

Tags: haskell, types, type-systems

When I was experimenting with Haskell kinds, and trying to get the kind of `->`, and this showed up:

```
$ ghci
...
Prelude> :k (->)
(->) :: ?? -> ? -> *
Prelude>
```

Instead of the expected `* -> * -> *`.
What are the `??` and `?` things? Do they mean concrete types or "kind variables"? Or something else?

Comment: This question is now historical. Since around GHC 7.4, the kind of `(->)` is now just `* -> * -> *`, even with `PolyKinds` enabled.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

These are GHC-specific extensions of the Haskell kind system. The Haskell 98 report [specifies only a simple kind system](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.1.1):

> ... type expressions are classified
>   into different kinds, which take one
>   of two possible forms:
>
> The symbol * represents the kind of
>   all nullary type constructors. If k1
>   and k2 are kinds, then k1->k2 is the
>   kind of types that take a type of kind
>   k1 and return a type of kind k2.

GHC [extends this system](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.50.231) with a form of kind subtyping, to allow [unboxed types](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/primitives.html#glasgow-unboxed), and to allow the function construtor to be polymorphic over kinds. The kind lattice GHC supports is:

```
             ?
             /\
            /  \
          ??   (#)
          / \     
         *   #     

Where:       *   [LiftedTypeKind]   means boxed type
             #   [UnliftedTypeKind] means unboxed type
            (#)  [UbxTupleKind]     means unboxed tuple
            ??   [ArgTypeKind]      is the lub of {*, #}
            ?    [OpenTypeKind]     means any type at all
```

Defined in [ghc/compiler/types/Type.lhs](http://darcs.haskell.org/ghc/compiler/types/Type.lhs)

In particular:

```
> error :: forall a:?. String -> a
> (->)  :: ?? -> ? -> *
> (\\(x::t) -> ...)
```

Where in the last example `t :: ??` (i.e. is not an unboxed tuple). So, to quote GHC, "there is a little subtyping at the kind level".

For interested souls, GHC also supports coercion types and kinds ("type-level terms which act as evidence for type equalities", as needed by [System Fc](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~chak/papers/SCPD07.html)) used in GADTs, newtypes and type families.

Comment: Exciting as this all is - are there any cases where a user (as opposed to a compiler implementer) might care about / need to explicitly take advantage of these boxed/unboxed kind distinctions?

At a superficial glance they seem like a bit of an abstraction leak of some internal inference mechanism used for optimisation within the compiler?

Comment: You'll care if you try to write functions that use types of kind other than '*' -- as they have various restrictions on how you can compose.

Comment: To me this looks like an abstraction leak as well. Programming languages are about exposing the right level of abstraction to the developer. I think here this is one level down to deep.

Comment: In new GHC, `(?)` and `(??)` were renamed to `OpenKind` and `ArgKind`, and now `(->) :: * -> * -> *`. http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/glasgow-haskell-users/2012-June/022435.html