# In GHCi, why does the kind of the function arrow `:kind (->)` include question marks `(->) :: ?? -> ? -> *`?

Tags: function, haskell, types, ghci

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Haskell Weird Kinds: Kind of (->) is ?? -> ? -> *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034264/haskell-weird-kinds-kind-of-is)

In GHCi (version 7.0.2), if I ask for the kind of the function type, the result has question marks:

```
Prelude> :kind (->)
(->) :: ?? -> ? -> *
```

Why does the kind include question marks instead of just asterisks `* -> * -> *`?  What do the question marks mean?  Why do other types just use asterisks?

```
Prelude> :kind (,)
(,) :: * -> * -> *
```

Comment: IMO, I would like it more, if GHC would only display these extended contexts if a special pragma is given to GHCi, as they confuse the beginner.

Comment: See also Don Stewart's more detailed explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034264/haskell-weird-kinds/3034295#3034295).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `?` and `??` kinds refer to GHC extensions, specifically unboxed types.  http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/IntermediateTypes has a diagram showing relationships between the extended kinds `?` (all possible types), `#` (unboxed types), `??` (boxed or normal unboxed types — "least upper bound of `#` and `*`"), `(#)` (unboxed tuples, which can only be used in a small number of contexts).  (The standard kind `*` refers to normal boxed types.)